# IntelliJ IDEA: Power Save Mode или Highlighting Level?

Tags: intellij-idea

Чем в IntelliJ IDEA отличается Power save mode от Highlighting level на уровне none?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничем не отличается, кроме значка в статусбаре.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/470785)

Comment: @Radzhab Является ответом на вопрос. И уточнять у автора нечего.

Comment: Одно отличие заметил: Power Save Mode включается для работы в IntelliJ IDEA впринципе, Highlighting Level только для отдельных файлов. Пробовал через верхнее меню (для мода во вкадке file, для уровня во вкладке analyze), и через статус бар. Но какими-то способами возможно и по другому  можно сделать, не знаю.